# GUI disappearing mysteriously

Tags: interface, blender-internal-render-engine, linux

I asked/posted this problem already, but some slug closed it. So now I have to repost this same question again because I can no loger update my prior question coving this same subject matter.

everything was working right up until it did it again. while moving my mouse arrow over anything on the side panels they just begin to disappear. I have found that if I grab the edges and close them then pull them open again they do redraw. this is only with blender I can switch to a different desktop and I get no ill-effects to any other GUI apps whatsoever.

[image: Menus are gone]

My memory is set to 10240, I have 16GB RAM. I have no real idea why this is taking place. I'm running void linux using the "linux" ATI/AMD drivers for my card.

when I create  a new file does not appear to have the same effect.

[image: Perfectly normal. (Menus are stay)]

Comment: There's no question here!

Comment: @Georges yeah but there is now. :D

Comment: Sorry, already flagged, why didn't you prepare the question properly and post it in the first time?

Comment: Anyways, this is obviously a bug, perhaps this is why your previous post were closed, you can report this to Blender foundation, I don't think you'll get any answers here

Comment: Check that you are using the correct drivers for your graphics card.

Comment: @Georges 4 the courisous mind. because I got mixed up with how to do uploads in here, and selected that blender file option that is a completely different sight that requires the http to a blender question first before allowing an upload of a file. oopps images have a different selection to do this... :D

Comment: read the help section for the site blend exchange site: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: @cegaton I'm running linux with its ATI/AMD drivers for my card. it stops doing this if I remove that one plane I added. it goes back to being ok again. I just noticed that right now. haven't experiemented with it yet.

Comment: @Georges that does not work unless I have a compelted http to a question in here first. I've tried doing this before psoting before and it does not allow an upload until I have a posted question http to it prior to it allowing me to upload a blend file. .....

Comment: AMD/linux and blender  are not great  combination. Do a search on this website, I believe the answer is using some version of the proprietary drivers. But I'm not sure. Use the search box at the top right of the page

Comment: @cegaton [link]( http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40689/2-76-how-to-use-ati-amd-gpu-without-linux-proprietary-driver) its a hit and miss situation.